# Absolute centering of a div over an image with CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have an image and want to use font awesome circle icon in center of that image. Can I do this?

```
<div class="poster">
  <img src="img/6.jpg">
  <div id="font">
    <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to do this play font icon on the middle of the image so how can i do ?
i have also tried in css

```
.poster{
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  border-width: 12px solid red;
}

.far{
  margin-right: 
  color: white;
  transition:transform 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to center everything in the `div`. Then apply `position: absolute` to your icon to place it on top of the image.

```css
.poster {
  /*margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -250px;*/
  border: 12px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.poster #font {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="poster">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200">
  <span id="font">
    <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank but  i use a background image on top of that image and upon the font awesome icon and want to left shift that image with in middle that icon

Comment: Sorry, I can't really visualise what you're describing. Could you update your question with the code you're actually working with, and the result you want, thanks

Comment: thanks for your support. here i am giving my all code to u and describe what i actually want to do  <div>

      <h1>this is heading one</h1>
      <h2>this is heading two</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur <br>
        adipisicing elit. Est, eum.</p>
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
</div> div{
    background-image: url("img.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
} i have a background image name img.jpg and and another image name 2.jpg i want to float left 2.jpg and the text to right and the font awesome icon middle of the 2.jpg

Comment: i don't want to cover all the page with  this background  image only my 2.jpg and text will appear on to it rest of page will continue as normal page